# adding helper comment to a field laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, database-schema

I am building a laravel application.I encountered a situation where i want to add helper comments for a field.I have a field status and due to requirement,i have to save the statuses as numbers 0,1,2,.. where the number indicates the following statuses

```
0 for inactive
1 for active
2 for pending
....
```

Now i want to save the statuses as enum having values 0,1,2 and want to add a helper comment to indicates the meaning of these numbers i.e., 0 for inactive,etc.

[image: Helper comment]

Is it possible to add a helper comment to any field using laravel schema??If yes,then how can i do so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel supports sqlite, mysql, postresql and sql server right out of the box.

The table comments doesn't exists in everyone of these DBMS.

Hence, it is not written in Schema builder.

You can execute MySQL specific raw query such as example:

```
DB::statement( "ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) COMMENT 'id of user' " );
```